# How to start app when phone starts with smartface.io

Tags: android, alarmmanager, smartface.io

I am using Notifications.local.scheduleNotification to schedule a notification.  However, if the phone is rebooted before the fire event, the notification does not fire.

I would like to have the app start when the phone boots up so that I can add the notification to the alarm manager again.  In the android manifest I would be asking for the following permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

How can this be implemented in smartface?

Comment: I couldn't understand your problem exactly. Are you trying to use this permission? Or you already added this permission to AndroidManifest.xml and the problem is it is not working?

Comment: I want to re add notifications to the alarm manager if the phone is turned off.  This is for smartface.io, and I am not sure if this feature is supported.  The only reason I showed the permission was to be clear about what I would like to do.  I have not added the permission to the manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, this is not supported by Smartface, but there will be plugin support soon, you can write your own plugin and use it.

Also for licenced users, there is an option to ask for new implementations. If they need some new features, they can report them to Smartface team, and these features will be added to road map.